# Conditional broadcastWith in Laravel Event?

Tags: php, laravel, broadcast

I have an event that would dispatch information on multiple channels:

- A channel for `members`
- A channel for `managers`

I wrote this:

```
<?php

class ModelUpdated implements ShouldBroadcastNow
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $model;

    public function __construct(Model $model)
    {
        $this->model = $model;
    }

    public function broadcastWith($who)
    {
        if ($who == "model.{$this->model->id}")
            return [$this->model->id];
        else if ($who == "model.{$this->model->id}.managers")
            return [$this->model];
        else 
            return [];
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return [
            new PrivateChannel("model.{$this->model->id}"),
            new PrivateChannel("model.{$this->model->id}.managers")
        ];
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, the `broadcastWith` doesn't work with my `$who` magic. Is there an alternative way of doing it?

I would like to avoid having different events because mine is triggered in the model:

```
class MyModel extends Model
{
    use Notifiable;
    
    protected $dispatchesEvents = [
        'saved' => ModelUpdated::class,
        'updated' => ModelUpdated::class,
    ];
}
```

Comment: what is model in code?

Comment: An Eloquent Model

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know `broadcastWith` [does not accept any parameter](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Notifications/Events/BroadcastNotificationCreated.html#method_broadcastWith), Laravel 8.x.
You need to pass all your data through the constructor, then, make decision on what you need to return as event's payload.

Make sure to [return an array](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#broadcast-data) from the `broadcastWith()` method.